# Set MDC variable in the main thread

Tags: java, spring, tomcat, slf4j, spring-boot

I need to log a constant value on each log line but the problem with the value is that the only way to get it is with code (I need to call and api first to get the value). So I want to find out that value at the start of the application and then set it in the main thread so then every new thread inherits that MDC context with that value already set.

Currently I'm using spring-boot so I tried to set it with an ApplicationListener:

```
@Bean
public ApplicationListener<ContextRefreshedEvent> setLoggingContext() {
    return new ApplicationListener<ContextRefreshedEvent>() {

        @Override
        public void onApplicationEvent(ContextRefreshedEvent event) {
            MDC.put("instanceId", "THE-VALUE");
            LOGGER.debug("Instance id set");
        }
    };
}
```

That code produces this log:

```
12:18:59.096 [localhost-startStop-1] default  INFO  o.s.j.e.a.AnnotationMBeanExporter -  Registering beans for JMX exposure on startup
12:18:59.171 [localhost-startStop-1] default THE-VALUE DEBUG c.m.config.CommonWebConfiguration - Instance id set
12:18:59.181 [localhost-startStop-1] default THE-VALUE INFO  o.s.boot.SpringApplication - Started application in 5.917 seconds (JVM running for 15.429)
12:18:59.193 [main] default  INFO  o.a.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol - Starting ProtocolHandler ["http-bio-8081"]
12:18:59.205 [main] default  INFO  org.apache.coyote.ajp.AjpProtocol - Starting ProtocolHandler ["ajp-bio-8009"]
12:18:59.207 [main] default  INFO  org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina - Server startup in 14291 ms
```

As you can see, the value is set in the thread called `localhost-startStop-1` so then in the main thread is not set anymore. Whay I would like to do is to set the MDC in the main context but I don't find a way to access to the main thread with spring running inside a servlet container.

I know that I can achieve the same thing with %contextName variable of logback but I would like to keep using the interfaces of slf4j without using something from one of the implementations.

Comment: How did you launch the app. If there's a main method it must be called in the main thread?

Comment: I'm using spring-boot. I read the whole documentation but I could not find any hook to the main method http://projects.spring.io/spring-boot/

Comment: Normally with Spring Boot you write your own main method. I'll ask again: how do you launch the app?

Comment: I didn't know that much because someone else wrote the initial structure of the project but you were right. We are launching the app with SpringBootServletInitializer. I tried to set it there in the #configure method but it is still the same thread `localhost-startStop-1`

Comment: If you are running in a container then none if your code is going to run in the "main" thread, so I guess the way to approach it is to set up the MDC in a `Filter`.

Comment: Yes I tried to do that and it works but it is still not what I want. I don't want to set it in the filter because 1) I'm going to set the same thing on each request. 2) If I run a batch task I'm not going to have that value set and I need it for every kind of log.

So I'm still preferring the contextName of logback. Thats exactly what I need but it is just that I did not want to use something specific from logback while I'm using slf4j in the rest of my code.

Comment: Thanks for the help! I'll leave it like it is and see if someone else came up with a different solution. But I don't think there is one at the moment.

Comment: I did this using Filters, for a project. Had a utility class for setting into MDC context and the utility was called from the filter. This was done so that we have the ID's from the very startup of Project!